# How to pass an inner hashMap with same keys inside an outer hashMap with different keys?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

```
public static HashMap<String, HashMap<String,Object>> getDataDictionary() {
    // Virtual Data Creation - Simulating The 9 Fields HAR value
    HashMap<String,Object> valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String,Object>> fileNameConstrains = new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Object>>();
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("A", 10);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("B", 20);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("C", 30);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("D", 10);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("E", 5);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("F", 20);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("G", 1);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("H", 100);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("I", 66);
    fileNameConstrains.put("File1", valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("A", 10);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("B", 50);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("C", 30);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("D", 90);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("E", 5);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("F", 20);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("G", 10);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("H", 90);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("I", 61);
    fileNameConstrains.put("File2", valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("A", 10);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("B", 60);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("C", 30);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("D", 2);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("E", 13);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("F", 9);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("G", 15);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("H", 88);
    valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("I", 69);
    fileNameConstrains.put("File3", valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields);

    return fileNameConstrains;
}
```

In this case, I am getting only the last set, all data are getting overridden, can anyone help me to figure out how can I pass data in the format like below?

> {Key="File1", value={'a'=10,'b'=5}}

And so on.

Comment: The fileNameConstrains map has all its keys referring to the same map object.  So changing the map for one key will be reflected among all the keys’ values that share the object.   You need to declare a new map for each key if that is not desired.

Comment: You add `valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields` as a value inside `fileNameConstrains`.  You then make changes to `valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields`, *which changes the state of the one inside `fileNameConstrains`*, because it's still the same HashMap.  You need to create a **new** HashMap using `valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields = new HashMap<String,Object>();` after you add it to the outer map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason why your data get overridden because you use the same key in the inner map 
as the documentations says the key for the map should be unique

so to solve your issue here you have to reinstate the map on every new file

```
HashMap<String,Object> Map1 = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String,Object>> fileNameConstrains = new HashMap<>();
    Map1.put("A", 10);
    Map1.put("B", 20);
    fileNameConstrains.put("File1", Map1);
    Map1 = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    Map1.put("A", 10);
    Map1.put("B", 50);
    fileNameConstrains.put("File2", Map1);
    Map1 = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    Map1.put("A", 10);
    Map1.put("B", 60);
    fileNameConstrains.put("File3", Map1);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign a new `HashMap` instance to `valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields` every time you want to store values into it and subsequently storing `valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields` into `fileNameConstrains` as follows:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getDataDictionary());
    }

    public static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>> getDataDictionary() {
        // Virtual Data Creation - Simulating The 9 Fields HAR value
        HashMap<String, Object> valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields;
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>> fileNameConstrains = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>>();

        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("A", 10);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("B", 20);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("C", 30);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("D", 10);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("E", 5);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("F", 20);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("G", 1);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("H", 100);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("I", 66);
        fileNameConstrains.put("File1", valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields);

        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("A", 10);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("B", 50);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("C", 30);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("D", 90);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("E", 5);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("F", 20);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("G", 10);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("H", 90);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("I", 61);
        fileNameConstrains.put("File2", valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields);

        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("A", 10);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("B", 60);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("C", 30);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("D", 2);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("E", 13);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("F", 9);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("G", 15);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("H", 88);
        valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields.put("I", 69);
        fileNameConstrains.put("File3", valueFromEachOfThoseNineFields);

        return fileNameConstrains;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{File3={A=10, B=60, C=30, D=2, E=13, F=9, G=15, H=88, I=69}, File2={A=10, B=50, C=30, D=90, E=5, F=20, G=10, H=90, I=61}, File1={A=10, B=20, C=30, D=10, E=5, F=20, G=1, H=100, I=66}}
```